# Vue-material stepper submit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, material-design, vuejs2, vue-material

How can I submit a vue material stepper?
I tried wrapping the `md-stepper` tag with a `form` tag like:

```
<form @submit="onSubmit">
  <md-stepper md-vertical class="stepper">
    ...
  </md-stepper>
</form>
```

But it is not working

So my question is how do i use the 'FINISH' button as a submit button or what's the right way to submit that form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply bind your `onSubmit` handler to the `completed` event on the stepper component...

```
<md-stepper @completed="onSubmit" md-vertical class="stepper">
  ...
</md-stepper>
```

There's no need for a `<form>`.

Comment: @GustavoOrdaz good to know. It's a shame they haven't documented the events emitted by the component. I had to look in the source code